# Apply CSS to the words in a paragraph written in brackets (parenthesis)

Tags: html, css

Guys here's the situation. The words in the `<span>` element are coming from a resource key. And the ones inside the parenthesis need to have slightly different CSS. For example -

```
<span>Hello this a wonderful resource. (I mean it)</span>
```

Now the requirement is, "I mean it" should have smaller font than rest of the words. The reason is, "I mean it" is an afterthought and the text overflows weirdly due to large font and they don't want to allocate another resource key for it. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Wrap the part with brackets within another span and apply style on it with a class.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I know that. They don't want to do it because they'll have to allocate another resource key for it. (The words come from database)

Comment: You can't style a textnode without wrapping it in an element so unless you can do it when it comes out of the database, you will need to wrap it with some js

Comment: Currently no CSS selector available for selecting text. Either you have to use the javascript to wrap the text with element and give the CSS to element or while writing it to html use element for wrapping text.

Comment: I'm not sure this could be done just using css (I would love to be proved wrong). Is there a reason to not use a little bit of js to wrap the parenthesis in an additional span?

Comment: add in your Database a balise with your specific css like  <i>(I mean it)</i> ? Or Use JS to find Brackets and adapt the CSS

Comment: _“The reason is, "I mean it" is an afterthought”_ – then it should be marked up in HTML as such to begin width. Maybe `em` would be the appropriate HTML element, perhaps even `ins` if that “afterthought” can be considered to have happened later …

Comment: The database is not under my control guys..

Comment: can you use javascript? @SagarRaj also can you just remove `(I mean it)` completely?

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't going to be able to tell which parts of a text in a given language are parenthesized (and what if there are nested parenthetical statements (such as these)?).

If you want your dynamic content to have rich formatting, then you're going to have to either store the content with some sort of formatting rather than in plain text, or use some kind of script to apply it on the client side if you absolutely cannot store formatting metadata with your strings in the database.

Comment: Hmm. I understand. But the database is not under by control. I'll give them the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't style. Only ::first-letter and ::first-line exist in CSS. Anything else must be done manually with an element (e.g. span).

or

Use lettering.js(refer this website http://letteringjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for you as im not sure how much control you have over the text and the consistency of the words but one way could be actually setting the content with `:after`

*definitely not a best practice*

**Method 1:** Set content via :after (assuming you can edit text in the database)

```css
span:after{
  content:" (I mean it)";
  font-size:.7em
}
```

```html
<span>Hello this a wonderful resource.</span>
```

**Method 2:** Simalar to method one but this is assuming you dont have acces to modify text **(pretty sloppy)**

```css
span{
  position:relative
}
span:after{
  content:" (I mean it)";
  font-size:.7em;
  background:#FFF;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  padding:5px;
  width:7em
}
```

```html
<span>Hello this a wonderful resource. (I mean it)</span>
```