# Calculate number of letters and apply CSS

Tags: html, css

Guys this question is related to this one > [Apply CSS to the words in a paragraph written in brackets (parenthesis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427854/apply-css-to-the-words-in-a-paragraph-written-in-brackets-parenthesis)

As the databse is not in my control, i'm trying to find some alternatives. Is there a way in CSS to count the number of characters in a sentence and then apply CSS to the rest of the characters?

Comment: From what I know: NO, you'll need javascript

Comment: There is really not much you can do with text in CSS beyond what is given in the text-* properties and the ::first-letter and ::first-line pseudo-elements.

Comment: Do you have access to add JavaScript to the site ? If you do you could use the JavaScript str.lengh and then JQuery.addClass() to add a class to apply the css

Comment: You could count text with `ch`

Comment: No, CSS can not read the content of an element or manipulate the document object model.

Answer (score 1):

1ch = width of a "0" (zero)

1ex = height of an "x" (lower case)

ex seems more accurate. Like @BoltClock♦ said, it's not counting, but it's a way to limit the number of characters. I'd try to "do some CSS with the rest" but OP was not specific, and frankly, I have no idea.

**Update**

The best I can come up with is putting the remaining text in a `:after` and then style the content.

```css
p.fifteen { max-width: 15ex; outline: 1px solid red; }
p.seventeen { max-width: 15ch; outline: 1px solid red; }
p.fifteen:after { content: 'fghijklmnop'; font-size: 36px; color: red; }
p.seventeen:after { content: 'hijklmnop'; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: 900; }
```

```html
<p class="fifteen">123456789abcde</p>
<p class="seventeen">123456789abcdefg</p>
```

Comment: That's not counting text. That's setting a length based on the width of the 0 glyph. You can't do any "counting" by setting a length.

Comment: Yeah it's not counting, but it's a way to control text at a certain number of characters.

Comment: @zer00ne - The question is, if i want to apply a different CSS for abcdef, for example, bigger font size, how do i do it?

Comment: @SagarRaj ok it's not perfect, but it's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JavaScript to do that just use `somestring.length` like so:

```
var someString= 'abc';
var str = someString.length;
console.log(string);
```

Result: 3

Check this out for more info http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

or jQuery method is:

Html

```
<div id="selector">Some Text</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#selector').text().length;
```